# Trying to upload audio file with model, but getting "Not Found" error (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a 'Music' model which  allows a user to upload an audio file through the "FileField". The file gets uploaded to my media folder fine, but the player in the profile.html, comes back with 'error' and in the terminal it says "Not Found" followed by the audio files path.

I'm still new to django, so I'd appreciate it if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the error in the terminal:

**Not Found: /my-profile/djangoapp1/media/path/to/audio/05_-_Bicycle_Race.mp3
[13/Feb/2021 15:44:44]**

**"GET /my-profile/djangoapp1/media/path/to/audio/05_-_Bicycle_Race.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 6743**

**models.py**

```
class Music(models.Model):
    track = models.FileField(upload_to='path/to/audio')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    artwork = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
class MusicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Music
        fields = ['track', 'title', 'artwork']
        widgets = {
          'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':1, 'cols':1}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required 
def music_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MusicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            song = form.save(commit=False)
            song.artist = user
            song.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Track Uploaded')
            return redirect('my_profile')
    else:
        form = MusicForm()
    return render(request, 'feed/music_upload.html', {'form':form})
```

**profile.html**

```
        <h3>MUSIC</h3>
        <audio controls>
          <source src="djangoapp1/media/path/to/audio/05_-_Bicycle_Race.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

Comment: Where is the hard-coded `src` coming from in your template? You should most probably be getting the url for the music file from the model field: `src="{{ music.track.url }}"`. Have you configured the `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings and have the media directory being served by either the dev server or another web server?

Comment: I've got the mdeia root in settings as MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' ,   the file is in the media folder media/path/to/audio , i just copied the relative path and put it in the src="" , to see if the track would play, but does it not work with the relative path ?